# How to rerun/reuse class constructors

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I recently moved from es5 to es6 classes and stumbled across the problem, that I cannot call the constructor without new anymore.

In my specific case I want to avoid object creation and memory allocation. And thats why I want to reuse old objects (its a bottleneck in case you might ask).

So in es5 I did this:

```
// extend adds all given methods to the classes prototype
extend([myClass1, myClass2, ...], {
  fromArray (arr) {
      this.constructor(arr)
  }
})
```

This piece of code will pass in the array into the constructor which knows how to deal with it. That allows me to run performant code without creating lots of objects.

Well - This is not possible in es6 anymore. The only way I think this can be solved is to introduce an `init()` method which does the work of the constructor. However, as you can see, I need this features on many classes. Having an `init()` function feels like a hacky and bloated way to add the functionality back.
Its also not possible, to use an existing function as constructor which can be reused because this is no valid syntax:

```
class Foo {
    constructor: someReusableFunction // Syntax Error
}
```

I read about the withdrawn [call constructor](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/blob/master/workingdocs/callconstructor.md) which will solve a lot of usecases and mine kinda, too (all init stuff would go into the call constructor). They said, that this is better solved with decorators. However I am not sure how decorators would solve that problem.

The motivation of NOT allowing constructor to be called was, that it might be possible in the future with call-constructos which are now withdrawn. So is there a chance, that the limitation will be lifted?

My question:

- Is there any intelligent workaround other than the ones I mentioned?
- Is there a chance that function-calling a constructor will come back OR that the syntax changes, so that you can specify a reuseable function as constructor?

Comment: Regarding your second question, I doubt it. I'm pretty certain that `Foo()` will always by an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Having an init() function feels like a hacky and bloated way to add the functionality back.

You could just write a class that calls `init` during construction:

```
 class Constructable {
   constructor(...args) {
     this.init(...args);
  }

  init(a, b, c) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Then just extend that:

```
 class Test extends Constructable {
  init(a, b, c) { /*...*/ }
 }
```

so that the constructor gets inherited too and you can use it as:

```
 const test = new Test(1, 2, 3);
 test.init(4, 5, 6);
```

> Its also not possible, to use an existing function as constructor which can be reused

Actually it is, just add a constructor that calls the function:

```
 constructor(...args) {
  someReusableFunction.call(this, ...args);
 }
```

Comment: right answer, sad though that there's no way to do this for a superclass or a library where you don't own the class